# How do I set the ItemsSource of a DataGrid in XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, data-binding, xaml

I'm trying to set the `ItemsSource` property of a `DataGrid` named `dgIssueSummary` to be an `ObservableCollection` named `IssueSummaryList`.  Currently, everything is working when I set the `ItemsSource` property in my code-behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    private ObservableCollection<IssueSummary> IssueSummaryList = new ObservableCollection<IssueSummary>

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dgIssueSummary.ItemsSource = IssueSummaryList
    }
}
```

However, I'd rather set the `ItemsSource` property in XAML, but I can't get it to work.  Here's the XAML code I have:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dgIssueSummary" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding IssueSummaryList}" >
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProblemType}" Header="Problem Type"/>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Count}" Header="Count"/>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

What do I need to do to set the `ItemsSource` property to be the `IssueSummaryList` in XAML rather than C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make "IssueSummaryList" a property.  If you do this, you can bind to it directly.  You can't bind via Xaml to a private field.

You'll also need to set the `DataContext` to "`this`" (or use another method to get it to find the appropriate instance).

Comment: Isn't the DataContext thing only needed if you use the M-V-VM Pattern for binding ?

He seems to use just code behind files

Comment: @KroaX: No.  The binding works via a DataContext.  The MVVM pattern takes advantage of this, but Data Binding in WPF (and Silverlight) is always binding to a property on the DataContext being used by the UIElement.

Answer (score 1):

Your IssueSummaryList is private. You need to make it a Property with get and set

```
public ObservableCollection<IssueSummary> IssueSummaryList 
{
     get
     {
        // ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The XAML is correct, so the problem must be in the Binding.

- Is the ObservableCollection exposed as a property?
- How have you set the Binding? In the most simple case you use code like:

  this.DataContext=this;

in the Window_Load eventhandler